# Can't install software (Armory) - No install option

Tags: installation, software-center

I'm trying to create a offline BTC wallet using Armory. When I go to install it the software center pops up with 'Only install this file if you trust the origin" with an install button that can't be selected. I've tried to install via file > install but that's not available.

I think it may be a permissions issue but I'm not sure since I'm new.

How can I get around this to install the software?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

From the terminal type the following:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb
```

Comment: What does it does?

Comment: sudo means run this as a super user

Comment: dpkg is used to manually install and remove packages

Comment: The -i parameter is the shortened version of the  --install parameter